# What is time and size complexity Nsarray vs Nsmutablearray and nsdictionary vs nsmutabledictionary

Tags: ios, time-complexity, complexity-theory

how can we judge  object action performance over  Nsarray vs Nsmutablearray and nsdictionary vs nsmutabledictionary

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You don't. Both NSArray/NSMutableArray and NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary are "class clusters", or  whole families of classes where the system decides at runtime which specific implementation to use based on factors that are not documented. Presumably it takes into account the number of elements, the types of objects stored, and (for dictionaries) the data type of the key values.

The implementation is opaque, and subject to change.

The best you're going to be able to do is to do some testing with different conditions and graph the results.

Comment: Thank you Mr Duncan C. But elaborating my question is that what to select between Nsarray and Nsmutable array , For e.g.  while fetching object at index considering time & size complexity

Comment: Do you need to mutate the array? Use NSMutableArray.  Do you not need to mutate the array? use NSArray

Comment: Better yet use Swift arrays. They are faster than NSArrays.